# "Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'CA0513.ITEMAVGRATINGTRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation"

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, squirrel-sql

I'm creating a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ItemAvgRatingTrigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF rating ON Collectionitems
REFERENCING NEW AS newRow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Item
    SET rating = (SELECT AVG(Collectionitems.rating) FROM Collectionitems, Item WHERE
        Collectionitems.itemid = newRow.itemid AND newRow.itemid = Item.itemid)
    WHERE Item.itemid = newRow.itemid;
END ItemAvgRatingTrigger;/
```

Whenver I run the trigger by updating a row in Collectionitems I get squirrel returning this :

```
Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'CA0513.ITEMAVGRATINGTRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation

SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 4098
Position: 7
```

Executing SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM User_Errors;
```

Generates 1 error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored./n
```

I've read quite a few posts with others having the same problem but haven't found a solution yet, any ideas?

Comment: This is never going to work. You're going to end up with a mutating table exception. Your actual problem is twofold. You should reference the new values as `:newrow.` and you do need a carriage return / line feed before '/'.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've recreated the mutating table exception, please could you explain why this is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual reason for this failing to compile is twofold.

1. You should reference the new values as `:newrow`.
2. You do need a carriage return and/or line feed before `/`.

However, this trigger is never going to work. You're going to end up with a mutating table exception, `ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.` This is because you're referencing the table you're updating in a row level trigger. Simply put Oracle ensures a read-consistent view of the data.

In the trigger, you're in the middle of updating `Collectionitems`. Selecting from this table at the same time, in the same session, there are two possible states; updated and not updated. To ensure that your view is read-consistent Oracle raises this error.

In your particular case you might want to consider a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CNCPT411) rather than a trigger.

#### Further Reading:

- [Fix Oracle mutating trigger table errors](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `/` at the end of the trigger on a line to itself.

Comment: You recreated the trigger with the `/` on a separate line and it still gives you that error?  Are you creating the trigger in the `CA0513` schema?

Comment: What about `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER CA0513.ITEMAVGRATINGTRIGGER`?

Comment: returns "Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

Comment: Ah, that's because `SHOW ERRORS` is specific to SQL*Plus, but you're using Squirrel. Sorry.  Anyway, if you've reproduced the table-mutating error, then I'd guess you must have got rid of the 'invalid trigger' error message.

Comment: that would explain it, thanks and yes it's gone but now we're not sure why it is producing that exception!